# Get event source element as JQuery element

Tags: jquery, events, type-conversion, jquery-events

Very specific issue.
I have a js event object, of which I need to get, for example, the tag name of the source element.

Project constraint impose JQuery to be used as much as possible to satisfy very wide cross-browser requirements.

I think I could convert the standard event with `$.Event(event)`, then extract from jQuery's event the target attribute, and then obtain with `.prop("tagName")` the tagName of the element.
I expect the converted event to have target property, but it does not...

```
var Jevent = $.Event(event);
console.log($(Jevent.target)); //Undefined
```

Can somebody shed some light on JQuery event object, why my Jevent does not comply with [this page](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)?

Comment: why don't you use `console.log(event.target)`?

Comment: Because event.target is not crossbrowser, as IE uses srcElement.